# Get latest stable version git

Tags: git, git-clone

I use `git clone https://github.com/git/git.git` to clone locally and subsequently install git program.  Unfortunately when the install procedure end, the version of the software is `2.12.0.rc2.2g80ba04ed9`.

How to clone the latest stable version instead of a Release Candidate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Releases are marked with tags. Just check out the latest stable one, and build as you normally did. The current latest stable build is 2.11.1:

```sh
$ git checkout v2.11.1
```

For a more general approach, you could use `git tag` and some shell scripting to deduce the latest stable tag automatically:

```sh
$ git checkout `git tag | sort -V | grep -v "\-rc" | tail -1`
```

Comment: Thanks!
But if I haven't git installed on my O.S. I have to use `clone` command. Is there a way to clone a specific tag? 

Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Cyr you must have git installed, or else the clone won't work. :) If you pass the `--branch` argument to clone, this tells git to checkout this branch instead of master. Tags can also be used here, so you can use the `v2.11.1` tag as Mureinik suggested in this answer.

Comment: @Cyr you have git installed - that's how you can perform `git clone`. **After** cloning, you can switch to the appropriate branch, as I've shown in my answer above.

Comment: It was late and I was tired: I have forgotten that git is installed on my O.S., sorry! Anyway, thanks for the comment!